# The given key was not present in the dictionary when I am just declaring the value

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface

```
public interface ICar { }

public static class Car
{
    static Dictionary<Type, HashSet<ICar>> CarDic = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<ICar>>();

    public static void Add(ICar carVar)
    {
        var baseType = typeof(ICar);

        foreach (var t in carVar.GetType().GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (t != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t))      
            {
                CarDic[t].Add(carVar);
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface ITest : ICar

public class ITestClass : ITest
{
    public void test()
    {
        Car.Add(this)
    }
}
```

When I run test function its giving me error saying the given key was not present in dictionary. I don't understand I am just declaring the dictionary I don't understand why its giving me this error. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I dont understand i am just declaring the dictionary" - no, you're creating a dictionary and then looking up a key in it with `CarDic[t]`, and if `t` isn't a key in the dictionary, it will throw that exception.

Comment: As a side note, method names in C# are capitalized in [PascalCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions "C# Coding Conventions"). `public void Test()` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are adding items to the `HashSet<T>`-value but first you need to get it with `CarDic[t]`. If `t` is not contained this exception is thrown. So use:

```
HashSet<ICar> cars;
bool contained = CarDic.TryGetValue(t, out cars);
if(!contained) 
    cars = new HashSet<ICar>();
cars.Add(carVar);
CarDic[t] = cars;
```